# Google chrome console message explanation?

Tags: javascript, web

I know my question is a Stupid question, but one of my friend consider it a warning cause the code is running well but this massage appear so could someone tell me this message below is warning or error and why?

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: Is that `jQuery` code? If so where are the `$()` around the class name? Even if otherwise how can you just call `onClick` on a string literal?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing anything about your code, to me it's looking like your calling something like this on your on your code...

```
$('.content-items button').onClick("HIHI");
```

When in fact you need to something call this instead...

```
$('.content-items button').click(function() {
   console.log("HIHI");
});
```